# Maven compilation and run time error java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.isValid(I)Z on Tomcat 8 Server

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jdbc, tomcat8

I've been converting a large Java Web App to a maven project, but I've run into an error in a handful of classes originating from the tomcat-dbcp jar.  I get the following error messages from any class that needs to use BasicDataSource objects:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.isValid(I)Z
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.isValid(I)Z
```

Now I know this jar is present on the server (as it is default in our Tomcat8 installation).  So in maven I declared this dependency as such:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.26</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

But I'm still seeing this error.  What can I do to eliminate this error?

Comment: Which version of the Oracle driver are you using? You might want to try upgrading to a newer version.

Comment: The same one that is standard on my Tomcat8 Installation.  As far as I can tell, this is a driver conflict.  But if I don't include the driver on my war it says it can't find the class.

Comment: That doesn't really narrow it down. The `isValid(int)` method was added in JDBC 4 (Java 6), by the looks of it you are simply using a driver for an older Java version (ojdbc5, ojdbc14, etc); or an old version that doesn't fully implement JDBC 4.

Comment: I'm using ojdbc7, sorry, got mixed up with the jar in question.  I was thinking tomcat-dbcp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error did go away, though I have no idea why.  The pom entry is still the same and still running on Tomcat 8.  We did find a hacky temporary fix:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
    <version>12.1.0.1</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

But we reverted back at some point and it is working fine.