# Application working fine on tomcat 7, but doesn't work on Tomcat 8 after I add resource details in context.xml

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, jndi, tomcat8

The application gets deployed on tomcat 8 and am even able to open the URL of the deployed WAR file. But as soon as I add the Resource details in context.xml   and bounce the server, the server doesn't come up and I get HTTP 404 on hitting the URL.(adding the same in context.xml of tomcat 7 works fine)
Below is the part added in context.xml

```
    <Resource name="jdbc/ace" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           initialSize="5" maxTotal="20" maxIdle="1000" maxWaitMillis="30000"
           username="Username" password="password"
           driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
           url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@myservername.com:1521:DB_Alias" />
```

Below is the error I get (Am using the default web.xml that was shipped with the tomcat package):

```
04-May-2016 05:17:05.589 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
04-May-2016 05:17:05.716 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /opt/tomcat/apache_tomcat-8.0.32/apache-tomcat-8.0.32/webapps/RD.war
04-May-2016 05:17:21.116 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
```

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/RD]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:939)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1812)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.isValid(I)Z
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.isValid(DelegatingConnection.java:917)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnection.validate(PoolableConnection.java:282)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:356)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2306)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2289)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2038)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getLogWriter(BasicDataSource.java:1587)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:594)
        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:274)
        at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:94)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:841)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:152)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:829)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1084)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:663)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        ... 10 more

04-May-2016 05:17:21.133 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive /opt/tomcat/apache_tomcat-8.0.32/apache-tomcat-8.0.32/webapps/RD.war
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/RD]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:939)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1812)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)

Comment: Seems like you are using a wrong version of your driver. Re-check if you are using the correct version. (see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32533715/maven-compilation-and-run-time-error-java-lang-abstractmethoderror-oracle-jdbc)

Comment: Hey @JoachimRohde am not using Maven.

Comment: Which version of the Oracle JDBC driver JAR are you using?

Comment: @LukeWoodward It's the same as I was using in tomcat 7 - ojdbc14.jar

Comment: These are the other jars I added in $Tomcat_home/lib -  
`mail.jar
jms.jar
activation.jar
commons-lang.jar
rmm.jar
connector.jar
commons-pool-1.1.jar
commons-logging-api.jar
commons-dbcp-1.1.jar
commons-collections.jar
ojdbc14.jar`

Comment: You will need to upgrade the JDBC driver to a later version than that.  You'll need ojdbc6.jar or later.

Comment: Thanks @LukeWoodward I'll get that. Btw, is the `commons-dbcp-1.1.jar` OK? Because it seems tomcat 8 uses dbcp2.

Comment: @Keyur: to be honest I don't know for sure, but if I was in your situation I would try running your app without `commons-dbcp-1.1.jar`.  As you've noticed, Tomcat has its own version of DBCP2.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. My error was resolved after upgrading to ojdbc6.jar.